# Map multiple suspend functions to single LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

The company I just started working at uses a so called Navigator, which I for now interpreted as a stateless ViewModel. My Navigator receives some usecases, with each contains 1 suspend function. The result of any of those usecases could end up in a single LiveData. The Navigator has no coroutine scope, so I pass the responsibility of scoping suspending to the Fragment using `fetchValue()`.

Most current code in project has LiveData in the data layer, which I tried not to. Because of that, their livedata is linked from view to dao.

My simplified classes:

```
class MyFeatureNavigator(
    getUrl1: getUrl1UseCase,
    getUrl1: getUrl1UseCase
) {
    val url = MediatorLiveData<String>()

    fun goToUrl1() {
        url.fetchValue { getUrl1() }
    }

    fun goToUrl2() {
        url.fetchValue { getUrl2() }
    }

    fun <T> MediatorLiveData<T>.fetchValue(provideValue: suspend () -> T) {
        val liveData = liveData { emit(provideValue()) }
        addSource(liveData) {
            removeSource(liveData)
            value = it
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MyFeatureFragment : Fragment {
    val viewModel: MyFeatureViewModel by viewModel()
    val navigator: MyFeatureNavigator by inject()

    fun onViewCreated() {
         button.setOnClickListener { navigator.goToUrl1() }

         navigator.url.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { url ->
             openUrl(url)
         })
    }
}
```

My two questions:

- Is `fetchValue()` a good way to link a suspend function to LiveData? Could it leak? Any other concerns?
- My main reason to only use coroutines (and flow) in the data layer, is 'because Google said so'. What's a better reason for this? And: what's the best trade off in being consistent with the project and current good coding practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is fetchValue() a good way to link a suspend function to LiveData?
  Could it leak? Any other concerns?

Generally it should work. You probably should remove the previous source of the `MediatorLiveData` before adding new one, otherwise if you get two calls to `fetchValue` in a row, the first url can be slower to fetch, so it will come later and win.
I don't see any other correctness concerns, but this code is pretty complicated, creates a couple of intermediate objects and generally difficult to read.

- My main reason to only use coroutines (and flow) in the data layer,
  is 'because Google said so'. What's a better reason for this?

Google has provided a lot of useful extensions to use coroutines in the UI layer, e.g. take a look at [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines). So obviously they encourage people to use it.

Probably you mean the recommendation to use `LiveData` instead of the `Flow` in the UI layer. That's not a strict rule and it has one reason: `LiveData` is a value holder, it keeps its value and provides it immediately to new subscribers without doing any work. That's particularly useful in the UI/ViewModel layer - when a configuration change happens and activity/fragment is recreated, the newly created activity/fragment uses the same view model, subscribes to the same `LiveData` and receives the value at no cost.

At the same time `Flow` is 'cold' and if you expose a flow from your view model, each reconfiguration will trigger a new flow collection and the flow will be to execute from scratch.

So e.g. if you fetch data from db or network, `LiveData` will just provide the last value to new subscriber and `Flow` will execute the costly db/network operation again.

So as I said there is no strict rule, it depends on the particular use-case. Also I find it very useful to use `Flow` in view models - it provides a lot of operators and makes the code clean and concise. But than I convert it to a `LiveData` with help of extensions like `asLiveData()` and expose this `LiveData` to the UI. This way I get best from both words - `LiveData` catches value between reconfigurations and `Flow` makes the code of view models nice and clean.
Also you can use latest `StateFlow` and `SharedFlow` often they also can help to overcome the mentioned `Flow` issue in the UI layer.

Back to your code, I would implement it like this:

```
class MyFeatureNavigator(
    getUrl1: getUrl1UseCase,
    getUrl1: getUrl1UseCase
) {
    private val currentUseCase = MutableStateFlow<UseCase?>(null)

    val url = currentUseCase.filterNotNull().mapLatest { source -> source.getData()}.asLiveData()


    fun goToUrl1() {
        currentUseCase.value = getUrl1
    }

    fun goToUrl2() {
        currentUseCase.value = getUrl2
    }
}
```

This way there are no race conditions to care about and code is clean.

- And: what's the best trade off in being consistent with the project
  and current good coding practices?

That's an arguable question and it should be primarily team decision. In most projects I participated we adopted this rule: when fixing bugs, doing maintenance of existing code, one should follow the same style. When doing big refactoring/implementing new features one should use latest practices adopted by the team.